# state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: The state for version 1780 doesn't exist in loadedMaps

Tags: pyspark, window, streaming, structure

I am using Spark 2.4.0, kafka 2.10.
I am currently working on a Spark Structured Streaming window job and running on YARN. it seems that on every batch interval I get the warning then the job is down:

> WARN state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider: The state for version 1780 doesn't exist in loadedMaps. Reading snapshot file and delta files if needed...Note that this is normal for the first batch of starting query.

[the warn log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia9fL.png)

[the stdout log picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOoRk.png)

Here is my code:

```
df.writeStream\
    .foreachBatch(handle_kafka.__execute)\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/hive/warehouse/tempdb.db/kafka_silver_gamelog_streaming") \
    .outputMode("update")
    .start()
```

Please help me out for the same. There may be workarounds for this issue, please suggest me if any.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure out the issue ? I am also getting the same issue.